# How to update in html page during nodejs readline process

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-webkit

I want to dynamically change the content of a

element in my html page during nodejs readline process.

Here is a jsfiddle example to shown the display effect I want to fulfill:
https://jsfiddle.net/09kuyn7v/

But I want to **dynamically display lines from my local file**, but not from an array defined within the function as in the jsfiddle example.

I have used readline module in my read-file-version clickTest() function:

```
function clickTest(){
  var fs = require('fs');
  var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  });

  lineReader.on('line', function(line){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += line;
  });
}
```

But when I click the button, the page was just like being freezed and then the lines were displayed simultaneously (not one by one as shown in the jsfiddle example above).

Comment: You are mixing server and client side operations here. You cannot use fs module on client to read from file, and on node you can read the whole file and then send it down to client. So what you probably want is to read whole file and send it down to client which then sets the interval, or open socket down to client and keep sending lines from node to server as they are being read

Comment: @Tom Actually I have already used fs module to read from file (why cannot?). My problem is how to display the content in the html page.

Comment: do you clearly understand the difference between client and server? As long as I know you cannot read local files on client side (unless you explicitly select them in file input)

Comment: @Tom Oh god, dude... Forgive me I didn't see any connection between what you say and my problem. Ok, just let it be true as you say I may not know the difference between client and server. But I have actually READ my local file line by line -- I can use console.log to output those lines in the devTool. My question is how to output those lines **in my HTML page** dynamically(each time output just one line)…

Comment: Dude... The code you posted above just won't run in your client (browser) there is no `require` nor `fs` if I am not mistaken. Both are nodejs specific. Yes you can read local file if you specifically let user to select it and use html5 file apis. If you have that code, post it here and I can help you to fix it. Otherwise you **think** you are doing it in client but actually doing it on the server (even if its localhost, still a server)

Comment: @Tom Ok, I see the problem. Sorry for not making the question clear. As you can see, I added a node-webkit tag for this question. It means this is in a nwjs(node-webkit JavaScript) project. It is for running in nwjs.app not in any browser. In nwjs, you can conveniently use nodejs modules, like fs, readline and so on, to manipulate local file or any content from URLs(at least I use nwjs for those purposes).

Comment: Yeah that is completely different situation then. I will construct some answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, every time you call that function you do `require('readline')` and `require('fs')` so I would move that up the script.

I would suggest two approaches:

**Pausing read**

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

function clickTest(){
  var lineReader = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  });

  lineReader.on('line', function(line){
    // pause emitting of lines...
    lineReader.pause();

    // write line to dom
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += line;

    // Resume after some time
    setTimeout(function(){
      lineReader.resume();
    }, 1000);
  });

  lineReader.on('end', function(){
    lineReader.close();
  });
}
```

This approach should read one line, then pause and resume after some time you specify.

**Buffering lines**

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');
var lines = [];

function clickTest(){
  var lineReader = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  });

  lineReader.on('line', function(line){
    lines.push(line)
  });

  lineReader.on('end', function(){
    lineReader.close();

    printLine(0);
  });
}

function printLine(index){
  // write line to dom
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += lines[index];

  if (index < lines.length - 1){
      setTimeout(function(){
        printLine(index + 1); 
      }, 1000);
  }
}
```

This approach will save all the lines into an array and then slowly prints them out.

Please note that I haven't got node-webkit to actually test it, so you might find a bug in the code, but it should give you general idea

Comment: Thanks a lot. My file contains up to 10million lines. So I can only follow the first approach.

Comment: 10 million lines writing one a second? Sounds like horrible user experience to me... 10m lines printing one a second would take 116 days to print out btw.